# Cannot reach service in docker container despite port mapping with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have these file to start a webserver inside a docker container. I can see the service running in the container at port 8000, but I cannot access it via the web browser.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN mkdir /static
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN apt update && apt install -y build-essential time libgraphviz-dev graphviz
RUN conda create -n env -c conda-forge python==3.10 django==4 pip #&& conda init bash
COPY backend/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./backend /backend
WORKDIR /backend/
```

## docker-compose file

```
version: "3.3"
   
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    restart: always
    user: ${UID}
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/Dockerfile-backend
    env_file:
        - ./.env
    command: ./manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/backend/
      - ${STATIC}:/static/
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  
  db:
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    image: postgres:13.4
    volumes:
      - ${DB}:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

I am running docker on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM and I have a port forwarding to that VM. I used commands like `docker network prune` before, so I am not sure, whether I deleted a requirement. I also tried stopping the container and run `docker container prune` and `docker-compose up`, but it does not work as it should.

```
curl localhost:8000
>>> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service inside the container should be served at IP address: 0.0.0.0
For some strange reason 127.0.0.1 does not work.

Comment: You could specify to use: `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`